# How to setup k8s ingress for Angular SPA with multiple frontends?

Tags: angular, kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

How to set up k8s ingress (nginx) for angular single SPA?

I have 2 angular frontends:

- app #1. responsible for authentication, and admin side (all routes except /member)
- app #2. responsible only for the user side (/member)

Problem: app #2 cannot reach libraries because it's trying to read it from route "/", and route "/" is reserved by app #1.

I've tried to specify deployUrl (in angular.json)

```json
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
    "deployUrl": "member/",
  }
```

Still, data is not reachable.

[Browser error]:
[image]

[Browser error #2]:
[image]

Ingress config for app #1:

```yaml
rules:
 - host: www.{{ .Values.app.host }}
   http:
     paths:
       - path: /
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
             name: {{ .Values.ingress }}
             port:
               number: {{ .Values.app.port }}
```

Ingress for app #2

```yaml
rules:
  - host: www.{{ .Values.app.host }}
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /member(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: {{ .Values.ingress }}
              port:
                number: {{ .Values.app.port }}
```

Also, I've tried to enable the following options for app #2:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-prefix: '/member'
```

As a result - infinite redirect.

Please help and thank you in advance.

I've tried changing paths and annotations in ingress, also outputPath, and deployUrl in angular.json.

Currently, frontend #1 works perfectly fine but frontend #2 - no.